# Mishnah Berurah style commentary on the rest of Shulchan Aruch

Tags: product-recommendation, commentaries, shulchan-aruch, mishnah-berurah, aruch-hashulchan

*a little background—*
Chofetz Chaim wrote the Mishnah Berurah in a novel way, that one could learn his commentary and not *need* to read many others. He however kept the original text of the Shulchan Aruch, keeping it an essential part of the product. He also “invented” the other explanations on the side of his page for additional information and sources.

This is in [direct] contrast for example, with the Aruch Hashulchan who “rewrote” the book, excluding the direct Shulchan Aruch text.

The Mishnah Berurah was only written on Orach Chiam (1/4) on account of the enormous job at hand, and that it took up a majority of his life.

I have come across personally such “copycats” of the Mishnah Berurah, that present the same style of information, aiming at a similar goal. (Example pictures below)

One is on הלכות נדה in Yoreh Deah, written by Rabbi Moshe Mordechai Karp. (Printed in the back of the second volume of משמרת הטהרה.) And he actually says in the Sha’ar Page that he is following the *tzurah* of the Mishnah Berurah.

Another is on ‏ הלכות שכירות פועליםcalled ‘חלקת בנימין’ written by Rabbi Binyamin Cohen. (Although he does not state his goal as being to emulate the Mishnah Berurah)

the question—

Are there others who have taken on individually such projects, with similar goals? (Including the authors mentioned above) Are there enough of these style of commentaries that one could study any section of the Shulchan Aruch under this style?

**Karp**
[image]
**Cohen**
[image]

Comment: have you seen בדי השלחן

Comment: @DoubleAA I haven’t

Comment: Maharsham, Daas Torah

Comment: between the בדי השלחן, חלקת בנימין, and דברי סופרים you have most of יורה דעה covered

Comment: Honestly the Aruch Hashulchan may fit,but it isn't printed with the Shulchan Aruch,there is also the Darchei Teshuva

Comment: Nah, I specifically wouldn’t consider it that @sam

Comment: You have kaf hachaim on some of YD

Comment: mishnas hamishpat on parts of choshen mishpat. The best sefer and likut on it. toen v'nitat and avaida.

Comment: gufai halochos on nidda

Comment: zer hashulchan on bosor becholov

Comment: Most are available on the oitsar but the main one badai hashulcan isnt

Comment: Not on Shulchan Aruch, but Rav Chaim Kanievsky's Derech Emunah on Rambam Hilchos Zeraim is in the same style

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are many such kind of *seforim* on all parts of Shulchan Aruch (in fact, almost all of it). [Prof. Spiegel](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%92%D7%9C) in his recently published book, 'Amudim Be'toldot Ha'sefer Ha'ivri - Hadar Ha'mechaber' (449ff.) documents the wide range of this category of *seforim*. A number of examples -

Books on Yoreh Deah:

1. Halachah Berurah, R. Avraham Wilhelm (§66-67*)
2. Shurat Ha'din, R. Srayah Diblitski (*hilchot zeraim*)
3. Gufei Halachot, R. Yehoshua Heschel Wolhandler (*hilchot niddah*)
4. Shaarei Mikvaot, R. Yissachar Hazan (*hilchot mikvaot*)
5. Pitchei Mezuzot, R. Yissachar Hazzan (*hilchot mezuzah*)
6. Sefer Milah Ke'hilchatah, R. Yair Ezer (*hilchot milah*)

On Even Ha'ezer:

1. Mishnat Ha'ezer, R. Eliyahu Hauzi (§1-25)

On Choshen Mishpat:

1. Mishptei Tzedek, R. Yosef Dov Septimus (§1-38)
2. Mishptei Ha'choshen, mult. editors (*hilchot shecheinim* & *poalim*)

Also notable is 'Even Berurah' on the Even Ha'ezer section.

Answer (score 3):

There is the four volumes of מעעדני השלחן on Yoreh Deah covering from matnas kehuna through taaruvos.

Also Chelkas Binyamin has other volumes besides the one you mentioned.

Also Chelkas Binyamin's father has the בדי השלחן that DoubleAA mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Also there is maareches Hashulchan

Answer (score 1):

Besides what others have mentioned, there's *Kaf Hachayim* (by R' Yaakov Chayim Sofer, lived about the same time as the *Chafetz Chayim*) on *Orach Chayim* and parts of *Yore Dea*.