# Mishna Brurah style for Y.D C.M E.H

Tags: halacha, jewish-books

I understand that mishna brurah covers o.c however, what seforim are similar in style to the mishna brurah covers Y.D, C.M, E.H?

Comment: There are a lot on individual inyanim like Badei Hashulchan for example. Can't think of anything comprehensive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mishnah Berurah style commentary on the rest of Shulchan Aruch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92882/mishnah-berurah-style-commentary-on-the-rest-of-shulchan-aruch)

Comment: If you're learning those seriously you should probably have outgrown reliance on summary works like mishna berura

Comment: Alternately, only knows the old works and has mastered them

Comment: You think it's better to learn Shulchan Aruch with Nosei Keilim instead of Mishna Brurah for an example (even though the m"b kindve implied that one should learn his sefer Bec we can't do the above properly nowadays with limited time etc)? @DoubleAA

Comment: @Moshe someone with limited time isn't doing Yadin Yadin, and no one who is paskining should be learning only Mishna Berura on OC chas veshalom.

Comment: @DoubleAA I know someone who at the moment is doing Issur Veheter in depth at quite a slow pace. However he wants to have a good hekef of the rest of Shulchan Aruch so he learns it fast with Baer Heteiv.

Comment: @DoubleAA, who isn't limited on time? Number two, Poskim do pasken based off those type of seforim, albeit after learning the big boys

Comment: @Moshe I still stand by my comments...

Comment: Listen, I'd love to go through O.C - E.H inside the Tur B"Y etc and the Sh"A an Nosei Keilim. I simply don't have the time for that etc. Even to learn Sh"A with Nosei Keilim is time consuming and it's not that easy (not that it's meant to be). Mishna Brurah does an amazing job I gotta say. Yes it's more "Geshmak" when you've seen the Poskim he quotes beforehand, nevertheless it's still very good. Especially if you learn the Aruch Hashulchan and Kaf HaChaim afterwards. I think you definitely get a lot from the ones mentioned above. Torah I love

Comment: I believe there was a story recorded  in the Artscroll biography of R. Avraham Pam, where a student complained to him that Choshen Mishpat is so hard because there is no Mishnah Berurah. The rabbi responded: “What do you mean, you have the Ketzos and Nesivos!”

Comment: Guess that rabbi never learned mishna brurah

Answer (score 5):

בדי השלחן written by Rav Feivel Cohen on most of the major parts of YD inc. Ta'aruvos, Basav VeChalav, Nidda, Tzedaka, Aveilus.

On Zeraim, there is Derech Emuna by Rav Chaim Kanievsky. This is witten on the Rambam, not on the Shulchan Aruch - however it can be used together when learning Mitzvos Hatluyos Ba'aretz in YD.

חלקת בנימין written by R' Binyomin Cohen (who is the son of the author of בדי השלחן) also has written on some other parts of YD such as Challa and Bishulei Akum and as well as many parts of CM.

If you are looking for a brief concise summary of the main Poskim on the page, you should learn Shulchan Aruch with Baer Heteiv.

Answer (score 1):

You may find "Aruch HaShulchan" By Rabbi Yechiel Michel Epstein (1829–1908) as a good choice. It is very comprehensive but not at the same style as M"B. However it is one of the best Halacha books